# Conditonally replace NA with value from other rows

Tags: r, tidyverse

I got a large data set with a relatively large set of missing variable values in one variable. But since I know that the variable is dependent on time and spatial aspects I can impute the missing values easily by taking the value from another row with exact matching temporal **and** and spatial values. Assume the data generated below:

```
temporal <- c("Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday","Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Friday","Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday","Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Friday")
spatial <- c("North", "South","North", "South","North", "South","North", "South","North", "South", "North", "South","North", "South","North", "South","North", "South","North", "South")
value <- c(NA,2,3,4,5,6,7,NA,9,10,1,NA,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,NA)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(temporal, spatial, value))
```

Which gives the following dataframe:

```
    temporal spatial value
1     Monday   North    NA
2     Monday   South     2
3    Tuesday   North     3
4    Tuesday   South     4
5  Wednesday   North     5
6  Wednesday   South     6
7   Thursday   North     7
8   Thursday   South    NA
9     Friday   North     9
10    Friday   South    10
11    Monday   North     1
12    Monday   South    NA
13   Tuesday   North     3
14   Tuesday   South     4
15 Wednesday   North     5
16 Wednesday   South     6
17  Thursday   North     7
18  Thursday   South     8
19    Friday   North     9
20    Friday   South    NA
```

In this case, I want to replace the `value == NA` with the `value` from another row who has matching values on `spatial` and `temporal`.

Thus, the end result should look like this:

```
    temporal spatial value
1     Monday   North     1
2     Monday   South     2
3    Tuesday   North     3
4    Tuesday   South     4
5  Wednesday   North     5
6  Wednesday   South     6
7   Thursday   North     7
8   Thursday   South     8
9     Friday   North     9
10    Friday   South    10
11    Monday   North     1
12    Monday   South     2
13   Tuesday   North     3
14   Tuesday   South     4
15 Wednesday   North     5
16 Wednesday   South     6
17  Thursday   North     7
18  Thursday   South     8
19    Friday   North     9
20    Friday   South    10
```

I have tried to do this by using the `group_by` function in `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>%
  group_by(temporal, spatial) %>%
  mutate(value, unique(value[is.na(value)]))
```

But I receive the following error message:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..2`.
x Input `..2` can't be recycled to size 2.
i Input `..2` is `unique(value[is.na(value)])`.
i Input `..2` must be size 2 or 1, not 0.
i The error occurred in group 1: temporal = "Friday", spatial = "North"
```

Am I approaching this in a correct way? If yes, why doesn't my code work as (I believe) that it should? If no, what approaches are suitable?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mutate won't work because you did not assign any value to a variable. your `mutate()` should look like this `mutate(value = unique(value[is.na(value)]))`. Althought this will not be my approach. What I did below was create a look up table of distinct non NA values and then joined them onto the original dataset. valuedis should be the values you want.

```
temporal <- c("Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday","Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Friday","Monday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Tuesday","Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Friday")
spatial <- c("North", "South","North", "South","North", "South","North", "South","North", "South", "North", "South","North", "South","North", "South","North", "South","North", "South")
value <- c(NA,2,3,4,5,6,7,NA,9,10,1,NA,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,NA)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(temporal, spatial, value))

library(dplyr)


dfdis <- df %>% 
          filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
          distinct(temporal,spatial,value) %>% 
          rename(valuedis = value)

df2 <- left_join(df,dfdis, by = c("temporal","spatial"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `dplyr` method. We are grouping by `temporal` and `spatial`, and then arranging by `temporal`, `spatial` and `value`, because the NA values will automatically be placed below any non-NA values. Then we're using `mutate` to create `value` based on the number in the first row of `value`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(temporal, spatial) %>% 
  arrange(temporal, spatial, value) %>% 
  mutate(value = value[1])
```

A more concise method with `tidyr::fill`, that retains the structure of your rows:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(temporal, spatial) %>% 
  fill(value, .direction = "downup")

# A tibble: 20 x 3
# Groups:   temporal, spatial [10]
   temporal  spatial value
   <chr>     <chr>   <chr>
 1 Monday    North   1    
 2 Monday    South   2    
 3 Tuesday   North   3    
 4 Tuesday   South   4    
 5 Wednesday North   5    
 6 Wednesday South   6    
 7 Thursday  North   7    
 8 Thursday  South   8    
 9 Friday    North   9    
10 Friday    South   10   
11 Monday    North   1    
12 Monday    South   2    
13 Tuesday   North   3    
14 Tuesday   South   4    
15 Wednesday North   5    
16 Wednesday South   6    
17 Thursday  North   7    
18 Thursday  South   8    
19 Friday    North   9    
20 Friday    South   10
```